# Obtener registros de base de datos de un text area

Tags: javascript

Hola amigos tengo un problema obteniendo los datos de un `textarea`, si no inserto saltos de linea en el campo el formulario me los obtiene sin problemas(Formulario Modal) Pero si inserto saltos de linea al momento de registro, ya no me abre el formulario, o sea el problema esta obteniendo los saltos de linea.

¿Alguien sabe como solucionar este problema?

Obtengo el dato de la siguiente manera en `javascript`:

```
document.formname.textarea.value = textarea;
```

Comment: Qué significa "ya no me abre el formulario" exactamente?

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es provocado por los saltos de línea al ingresar el valor dentro del `TextArea`, puedes filtrarlo o si lo necesitas

```
text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '');
document.formname.textarea.value = text;
```

o cambiarlo por `<br>`:

```
text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br>');
document.formname.textarea.value = text;
```

Comment: HTML dentro de un input no se leerá como HTML, sino como texto dentro del input.